# Saving values ​locally with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

the code below allows you to save the parameters as sharedprences in the various devices, however during the execution of the code I am shown the following error. 
How do I correct this error?

**Error:**

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'
#0      Storage.salva (package:Myapp/utils/support.dart:17:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _LoginPageState._salvataggiovalorilogin (package:Myapp/ui/login_page.dart:659:15)
#2      _LoginPageState._buildSignUp.<anonymous closure> (package:Myapp/ui/login_page.dart:636:38)
#3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
#4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:236:7)
#9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:2<…>
flutter: Letto: 0
```

**Dart Code:**

```
//Dart View Code
  Storage.salva("1","sample");
  Storage.leggi("1");
  showInSnackBar("Parametri server configurati");

//Storage Class
class Storage {
  //Funzione che permette la lettura di un valore dalla memoria
  static void leggi(var name) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = name;
    final value = prefs.getInt(key) ?? 0;
    print("Letto: $value");
  }

  //Funzione che permette il salvataggio di un valore in memoria
  static void salva(var name, var value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt(name, value);
    print("Salvato $value");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passing a String value to your `salva` method. And you are saving it as an int in this line

```
prefs.setInt(name, value);
```

You should be using this instead.

```
prefs.setString(name, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `salva` you are passing in a String `"sample"` and the calling `setInt`. Make sure that you pass an Int into `salva` as the second parameter.

I would recommend using types rather than var to help with this on your function parameters

```
//Storage Class
class Storage {
  //Funzione che permette la lettura di un valore dalla memoria
  static void leggi(String name) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = name;
    final value = prefs.getInt(key) ?? 0;
    print("Letto: $value");
  }

  //Funzione che permette il salvataggio di un valore in memoria
  static void salva(String name, int value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt(name, value);
    print("Salvato $value");
  }
}
```